# Undefined References to OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, libraries, undefined-reference

I'm running 32-bit Windows 7 Enterprise and CodeBlocks 10.05.

I followed [this tutorial](http://opensourcecollection.blogspot.com.es/2011/04/how-to-setup-opencv-22-in-codeblocks.html) to set up OpenCV 2.2 to work with CodeBlocks.

Any programs that use the C CodeBlocks API work fine - they compile, link, and run fine.
However, when I try to use C++ OpenCV functions and objects, `.o` files are generated, but I get linking errors, such as:

> undefined reference to `` `cv::cvtColor(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int, int)' ``

After some Googling, I found that this was because I didn't include enough libraries in my search directories. However, I don't know what libraries to include.

After some searching in my OpenCV folder, I found some `.a` files in `3rdParty/lib` and added them, too. But my problem persists.

Does anyone know what libraries I have to include in order to get my program to work?

If you need more information, please tell me and I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the `libopencv_imgproc` library.

Comment: I just searched for it in my OpenCV folder, but I can't find it. Do you know where it is located?

Comment: @eboix Did you compiled sources?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my response. I didn't compile the source. I just downloaded the already-compiled OpenCV2.2.

Comment: Actually, it seems that I included `opencv_imgproc220d.lib` and `opencv_imgproc220.lib`. I'm not sure if these are the `libopencv_imgproc` you're talking about.

Comment: @eboix Yes, it can be so. I worked with opencv under linux, so it was `libopencv_imgproc.a` or `libopencv_imgproc.so` after library compilation.

Comment: So I should download OpenCV source and use CMake and make?

Comment: Okay. I'll accept this answer and proceed to building OpenCV from the source.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and tried the above which did not work and I have downloaded the precompiled OpenCV.

So what worked for me was to include the following header.

## include opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse

[image]

Of course , I assume you have already compiled the source folder with CMake. If you haven't done already refer to this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVyVEHK4qfQ

In the first 8 min, you will learn every configuration.